# Can the "Confirm Your Identity" modal, when using SBS, be translated?

Tags: docusignapi

I went through the whole "DocuSign - Signing Resource File v1.1" documentation trying to find a way to change the text messages of the SBS EU Advanced Signature modal but so far, I could not find a way to do it. 
[SBS EU Avanced Signature modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plyIq.jpg)

Using a resource file, is it possible to change the texts of this modal?

Regards.